# REST API - Get vs GetBrief/Shell in Controller

Tags: rest, controller, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

So if I have the following entity:

```
public class Guest 
{
   public int GuestId { get; set; }
   public bool HasCheckedIn { get; set; }

   // child/related entities
   public Person Person { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
   public Phone Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Please forgive/correct me if some of the terminology I use is not correct...

Assume we have turned off Navigation Properties which would automatically populate the child entities such as Person and Address.
If my website is calling the WebApi for specific data, sometimes it might need the 'full' Guest object with all of the child entities, in which case it might call the appropriate method in the Business Layer to backfill the object. In other cases, to keep the request light we might just want a 'shell' or 'brief' of the Guest with just the basic data that the underlying table would hold such as HasCheckedIn and all the child entities to just be null.

So what is the suggested approach here for the Api Controller? Should there just be one Persons Controller who's Get method is really a proxy to the GetFull method in the BLL Person class and then have a separate PersonsBrief Controller who's Get method is really a proxy to the GetBrief method in the BLL Person class? Or should this be one method in the Persons Controller which takes in a boolean for IsBrief or something?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches have merit but it may actually be clearer to separate the summary and details into separate resources.  It seems like your use cases between the two variations are distinct, which to me suggests that you should separate your resources accordingly.  In other words, implement two separate controller methods, one for "guest details" and another for "guest summary".